# Is there an IDE platform that doesn't require code to be organized by file?

Tags: functional-programming, ide

Moderately experienced but amateur programmer here. I've been transitioning to functional techniques after a lot of OO wrangling that always seemed to end up in a mess. But I've been considering that I really just don't find files to be a great way to organize code.

Is there any kind of IDE and plugin that handles the files for you and instead gives you a way to write functions and data structs independently with navigation done through references in code?

This is a rather generic question but for reference I use: Xcode, Android Studio, Sublime Text, and Arduino IDE. And I program in Swift/ObjC, Java, Python, HTML/CSS/JS/PHP, and C/C++

Comment: Every language and their diverse ecosystems of tooling work with files in unique ways. There are so many tool-specific and language-specific details that cannot be captured by such a short question asking about all of them in a post that fits the scope of what Stack Overflow is intended to do. This question is too broad, and besides:

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off-topic for reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons I have stated above: too broad / needs focus, and asking for tool recommendations.

Comment: Note: that's not to say I don't think this is an interesting idea. Just that you're probably better off asking per-language for the reason I stated above, and that this is not the right place to ask. Maybe check out reddit or quora or some other platforms.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. I wasn't really sure. I don't belong to programmer reddit communities and r/programming is links only.

Comment: To be honest, I never really understood how [SmallTalk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) source code persistence worked, but I did get the impression that it may not have been based on text files. I could easily be wrong, though.

Comment: In general, once you go beyond small hobby projects, you're going to need to deal with other pieces of the development cycle, which will include version control. Git, the predominant version control system, is file-based, which puts a practical constraint on other tooling. Thus, all major languages and IDEs are going to be file-based.

Comment: Oh I'm sure that you can't escape there being files. Every part of pretty much every toolchain is file based. I thought maybe someone might have figured out how to automate the organization into files and hide it from the user

Comment: IIRC, that was one of the original ideas behind [Light Table](http://lighttable.com/), but I haven't used it for a decade, so I don't know what the current status is.

Comment: You can get some of what you're asking for with some language and IDE combinations. For example, when writing C# in Visual Studio, I rarely interact with the file view. Instead, I navigate to definitions, find implementers or call sites, use pattern-based name searching, etc. Whether you can do that is entirely dependent on the combination of language and IDE. Even Visual Studio becomes weaker when the language is F# rather than C#. OTOH, I could image that there are other IDEs that offer a similar experience for Java.

Comment: Android Studio/IntelliJ is also really quite good for jumping around just by Cmd-Clicking. That's part of what made me think about it. I'm only starting down the path of functional techniques so I don't think I could survive in a pure functional language. I'd love to be able to write a pure function outside of everything because I don't know every place I'll use it. I think organizing by file forces people to couple code before those compromises even start needing to be made